# Why is my JavaScript code behaving strange?

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain why delete works in second function not in first?

```
var myFunction = (function (val) {
    delete val;
    return val;
})(10);
console.log(myFunction);


var myFunction1 = (function () {
    myVar = "test"
    delete myVar;
    return myVar;
})();
console.log(myFunction1);
```

Comment: Note that your variables are called `myFunction` and `myFunction1` but they don't actually contain functions, just the return value of functions. You should really pick better names.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delete operator is for deleting properties, not objects.

In the first function, `val` is a variable and can never be deleted. However in function2 `myVar` was declared using shorthand to create a property on the global object, and properties can be deleted. In fact this is the main purpose of the delete operator.

Also the delete operator returns a boolean value. you can use this to get a better understanding of how it works eg: in your case `console.log(delete val);` will print false and `console.log(delete myVar);` will print true. it is also worth keeping in mind the return value is based on whether the object exists afterwards, not whether the delete was successful.